# insert data into BigQuery using R

Tags: r, google-bigquery

i'm using bigrquery package to upload data into r but also i would like to insert table into BigQuery using that package (or any other package like JDBC).

im ruing the following script

```
insert_upload_job(project, dataset, "FaceBookAds_AdAccounts_5859_test", facebook_account, billing = project,
                  create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED")
```

and received that the job was ruing

```
$status
$status$state
[1] "RUNNING"


$statistics
$statistics$creationTime
[1] "1492590170100"

$statistics$startTime
[1] "1492590172646"
```

but i can't see the table in BigQuery

the table contain less then 100 rows

Answer (score 3):

i was able to insert table to BigQuery using bigQueryR package.

```
library(bigQueryR)

bqr_auth()
bqr_create_table(projectId=project, datasetId=dataset, "FaceBookAds_AdAccounts_5859_test", facebook_account)
```